# How to do an equal statement

Tags: php, forms

How can I use an equals statement that solves this issue:

```
$username = //drawn from db;

$posted = //posted by user on form;
```

If `$username = $posted` then process the form

If `$username != $posted` then print error.

How can I do this in one step?

Comment: In one **query**?? Queries can't print errors or process forms.

Comment: yes in one query.  I had a script that did i am not sure how to do it now.  Like if $username = $posted then echo "" if not then echo ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($username === $posted) {
   echo "welcome";
} else {
   echo "go away";
}
```

Comment: @AAA 2 == means equal, 3 === means identical.  See the PHP docs on comparison operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: `==` boils down to "equal,even if typecasting is required", `===` is "strictly equal, contents and type must match". `==` can blow up on you, as `0 == ''` is true, but `0 === ''` is false.

Comment: === is only really useful if you're looking for a specific value that can show up as multiple things.  For instance `0 == ''`,`0 == false`, and `0 == 0`, but `0 === 0` but not `false` or `''`.  It's mostly useful if a function can return nothing if nothing was found or false on error/failure, which if you did something like `if(function($var) == false)` it would run if the function returned nothing or false, but `if(function($var) === false)` would run only if the function actually returned false on failure or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, `=` is an [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).  You probably meant to use two equals symbols together (`==`) or three equals symbols together (`===`), which are [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Examples:

```
$user = "asdf"; // set the value of the $user variable to "asdf"

if($user == "asdf") { echo "The user's name is ASDF"; } // compare the value of $user to "asdf"
```

Comment: There we go.  Thats what i am looking for.  I looked over the page.  I can't find something similar to my needs.  Can you help with it.  I think it would be something like if $username == $posted {echo""; if not then echo ""

Comment: @AAA I added a simple example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways:

1. Extract the information from the database, with the $username and check wether there is an existing row
2. Have variables (as you did) and compare them with `==` operator or `===` if they have the same type.

Answer (score 1):

you can run this

```
<? $q=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT username FROM yourtable WHERE username='".$_POST['FormUserName']."' and pass="'.$_POST['FormPassword']."' LIMIT 1"));
        if($q['username']==$_POST['FormUserName'])
        {echo "You LOGGED";}
    ?>
```